# Is it possible to use the same MS Dynamics NAV 2016 service reference to access/commit changes to both International AND North American databases?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-dynamics, erp, navision

I have working mechanisms using a NAV Service Reference that I use to read/write Purchase Invoices to/from MS Dynamics NAV 2016 using an International database (I exposed the web service on an International database NAV setup and generated the reference schema from there). I now want to extend the existing C# code such that it may also be used with North American databases in NAV. I understand that certain fields in one database would not make sense to be set in another, as often they do not have the same fields (e.g. VAT-related and labelled fields (International db) vs. TAX-related fields (North American db)), but my code does not use such fields, the ones I use are common to both databases. My question, therefore, is: provided that I only read/write common fields in my code, is it possible to use a generic Service Reference to access several database types in NAV 2016, or do I need to add a database-specific Service Reference for each database I want to cover?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web service you don't care what is behind it. It might not even be a Nav. As long as wsdl (service contract or service definition name it as you like) match.

Be aware of decimal separators and date formats though. It might behave differently depending on locale settings of web service.